# Datastore Queries to retrive multiple values in GCP Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

How to retrieve multiple values in single field in datastore nodejs.
code:

```
const query = datastore.createQuery('Task')
.filter('user_id', '=', [1,2,3])

.order('priority', {
descending: true
});
```

this is not working.
I need query something like this

```
select userName from Table where user_id in (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: "IN" queries generally aren't supported in Datastore. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202516/doing-a-in-array-query-on-google-app-engine-datastore-with-golang

Comment: I have a problem with bigquery too there offset and IN are not working

Answer (score 1):

You can query to retrieve multiple values like the following:

If you have array of multiple datastore Id's like following:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

You can query with [gstore-node](https://sebelga.gitbooks.io/gstore-node) Package

```
var userData = await UserModel.get([1,2,3,4]);
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: Not Sure. But I recently used in this way and I get results. :)